# Java: implementing multithreaded supplier / consumer pipeline with parallel limitations per kind of tasks

Tags: java, threadpool, producer-consumer

We need to process different kinds of objects asynchronously. Each kind/type of objects is processed using API key.

Each API key has own limits on concurrent use (like no more than 5 parallel session for one API key).

We have global limit for count of working threads (CPU limits).

We'd like to make as many API calls as possible within working threads limit.

Possible solutions for:

```
2 tasks with KEY1 (max 2 session) -\  total 3 workers
5 tasks with KEY2 (max 3 session) -/
```

are:

```
1. worker1: KEY2, worker2: KEY2, worker3: KEY2 (in queue: 2x KEY1, 2x KEY2)
2. worker1: KEY1, worker2: KEY2, worker3: KEY2 (in queue: 1x KEY1, 3x KEY2)
3. worker1: KEY1, worker2: KEY1, worker3: KEY2 (in queue: 4x KEY2)
```

Possible solutions for:

```
3 tasks with KEY1 (max 1 session) & 3 workers
```

is:

```
1. worker1: KEY1, worker2: IDLE, worker3: IDLE, (in queue 2x KEY1)
```

Execution order doesn't matter (but we'd like to hear near first in first out like policy), maximum throughput is the most important.

It is not clear which implementation strategy to choose.

`ThreadExecutor` with any queue is not sufficient because you need to know which API keys are currently used by `ThreadExecutor`.

Comment: Why don't you use one executor per key, and a multiplexer in front that distributes each task to the correct one?

Comment: I have 200 API keys, and have limits for CPU. I can't just create 200 ThreadPools with 5 threads and choose one based on API key... Task is interesting by requirement from two sides.

Comment: Oh, so you basically want a main executor service with the global thread count, and a strategy to fill it depending on how many tasks of a given key are already active?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I got the question right, but what you need seems to be a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for each API key.

```
Semaphore key1Semaphore = new Semaphore(2);
Semaphore key2Semaphore = new Semaphore(3);
```

You can check if the `key1Semaphore` has permits and acquire one if available by calling `key1Semaphore.tryAcquire()`. This is non-blocking, so if it fails and returns false, you could try to acquire a semaphore from the other API key and submit a task from that.

It is important that at the end of the task using one of the API keys, the semaphore permit gets released back.

You might need an extra object to synchronize on with a `wait()` and `notify()`, so that when a task finishes it notifies the main thread that is dispatching tasks to check the semaphores again.

So essentially what you get is that your task dispatcher would submit 5 tasks to your `ExecutorService` of 3 workers, and then it won't be able to submit any more until one of the semaphore permits gets released.

When a task finishes and a permit gets released, the dispatcher gets notified, so it unblocks from waiting, and again checks the semaphores in order and submits the tasks to the `ExecutorService`.

This solution is a bit biased towards the first API keys, but you can refine it even more by checking the length of the tasks for each key and distributing them more fairly. You could even rotate the index, so that with each loop you increment the index by 1, so that the first time you start from API KEY 1, and the second time you start from API KEY 2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably create a service maintaining

- a single `Queue` containing entries consisting of the task and corresponding key,
- a `Map` with a key and the already running threads of that key (`Map<String,AtomicInteger>`), and
- a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the globally allowed thread count.

If the global thread count is full and a task is submitted, it is put to the end of the queue.

If the global thread count is not full, the map value corresponding to the request key is checked for the key thread limit; if it is reached, the task is put back into the queue, otherwise submitted to the executor service.

"submitting to the executor service" will not submit the task directly, but increase the key thread count, and wrap the task into a `Runnable` which will additionally 1. decrease the key thread count in the map and 2. trigger reevaluation of the queue so new tasks are submitted if applicable.

It might also be possible to create the "active count per key" logic in a `BlockingQueue` which will return as `first()` the next element containing a task for a key the max count has not been reached, and pass that as the management queue to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` constructor; but I'm sure that would break the queue contract and not be entirely safe to use.

Comment: You are spotted everything I worry about )) In simple cases queue is used as temporary storage for postponed tasks but in my case `next()` method should be aware about current thread executor state. The problem is I can't use any high level implementation of thread pools or executors  or queues and need to build solution from low level blocks.

Comment: I think about same approach to add surrounding logic to `Runnable` around original task and reuse `ThreadPoolExecutor`. At least that free me from implementing multithreading code. Tricky part is about returning task to queue (self-referencing may lead to "oscillation"/temporary 100% CPU load loop).

Comment: @gavenkoa yeah I wouldn't take the tasks out of the queue before I'm sure I can submit them, ie iterate until I find a valid one, and remove that. This does defeat the point of using a queue in the first place I guess.